# ruby c extensions: character values over 127

Tags: c, ruby, string, byte

I am trying to make a C extension for Ruby that includes a method returning a string, which will sometimes have character values that need to be in an `unsigned char`. In http://github.com/shyouhei/ruby/blob/trunk/README.EXT, all of the functions listed for turning C strings into Ruby strings take signed chars. So I couldn't do this:

```
unsigned char bytes[] = {0xf0, 0xf1, 0xf2};
return rb_str_new(bytes, 3);
```

How could I make a method that returns these types of strings? In other words, how would I make a C extension with a method returning `"\xff"`?

Comment: What's the problem if you simply remove `unsigned` in the code above?

Comment: @Marc-Andre Lafortune - removing the `unsigned` will not let me use values bigger than 127 because they will turn into negative numbers.

Comment: `char` isn't actually the same type as `signed char` - it's a type distinct from both `unsigned char` and `signed char`, and it is implemenation-defined whether or not it's signed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that ruby will treat negative chars as their unsigned equivalent when using `rb_str_new`. So, you can just cast the array of bytes to a `char *`.

```
unsigned char bytes[] = {0xf0, 0xf1, 0xf2};
return rb_str_new((char *)bytes, 3);
```